# How will ARMA be affected if a non-stationary time series is not made stationary?

Tags: time-series, arima, arma, stationarity

Which components or statistics of ARMA will be affected - and how - if the stationarity condition is violated?

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is, the stationarity assumption is needed because if it is violated, the impact multiplier will have a bigger impact period after period.
Whereas if the stationarity condition is respected, the impact multipliers of shocks tend to 0 quickly enough it i tends to infinity.

Comment: Are you sure you mean this: "the impact multiplier will have a bigger impact"? Also, what do you mean by "it i tends to infinity"?

Comment: Can you explain impact multiplier?